# JQuery - Pass dynamic variable to delegated event parameters

Tags: jquery

I know I can do like this, and my function will work.

```
var theRoom = 'room1';    

$('#notifyParent').unbind('click').one('click', '#' + theRoom + '321', function () {
    //do something
});
```

But how to do the same thing when `theRoom` is a dynamic variable that can change after the page is loaded? Is it even possible?

Comment: Use a class... the handler won't know the variable changed - the handler bound at runtime still exists.